# TABCTL32.OCX(1.1.0)

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration, ocx

I am trying to upgrade a VB6 project to run it on VB8, but I am getting an error which says that you need to install `TABCTL32.OCX(1.1.0)`.

What shall I do? Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To run the upgrade wizard you need VB6 installed on the machine, and also any controls used in the code you are upgrading.

- `Tabctl32.ocx` is the `Tabbed Dialog Control 6.0`, the standard tab control from VB6. If you install VB6 you will be fine.
- See Microsoft's [list of controls shipped with Visual Basic 6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194784).

Comment: Wouldn't a recommendation to upgrade the actual control used from that of the legacy VB one to the VB.NET TabControl be more apt? Just curious.

Comment: Actually the TabStrip control is more fundamental, based directly on a Windows control.  Its COM wrapper is in MSCOMCTL.OCX.  None of these are part of the runtime, but instead are extra tools supplied with VB6 - quite a few having 3rd party origins.  You might think of these as VB6's "Framework" rather than runtime.  A small point but I think it's important to call things by their right names to avoid miscommunication.

Comment: @Bob `TabStrip` is indeed in `MSCOMCTL.OCX`. However this question is about `TABCTL32.OCX` which is a different control, `Tabbed Dialog Control 6.0`. Check the link. I think your point about terminology is good, "VB6 runtime" ought to be restricted to things that are now installed with windows.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment You can't run the .Net upgrade wizard at all unless you have VB6 installed, and any controls used in the code. Then the wizard will (as far as I can remember) automatically replace the VB6 control with the .Net control. But you can't get to square one without first installing the VB6 stuff on your development machine. Think of it as the last farewell to VB6.